# User grpl on each element of a dataframe column to find a string in a different data frame

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lapply, sapply

I need to find if the elements on a data frame column are present in another data frame column in order to retrieve a count and a total.

**Example**

Data frame 1

```
Details<-data.frame(FirstName=c("Carlos SM","Carlos JOH","Carlos WIL","Carlos JON","Carlos BR","Peter D","Peter MILL","Peter WILS","Peter MOO","Homer T"),Points=c("3","4","7","6","4","9","1","2","1","9"))
```

Data frame 2

```
Results <- data.frame(Person=c("Carlos","Homer","Peter"))
```

The ideal output will add two columns to the data frame called Results one for the count of the times each string is found in the Details data frame and the other for a total sum of points. Like so

```
FirstName  Appearances  Total Points
Carlos          5             24
Perter          4             13
Homer           2             13
```

Comment: Is `Points` is a numerical or a character variable? Because in your example its a character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Results$Appearances=sapply(Results$Person,function(x) sum(grepl(x,Details$FirstName)))
Results$`Total Points`=sapply(Results$Person,function(x) sum(grepl(x,Details$FirstName)*as.numeric(Details$Points)))
Results
  Person Appearances Total Points
1 Carlos           5           22
2  Homer           1            7
3  Peter           4           11
```

Also, it seems like the numbers in your expected output are a little bit off. It is really confusing. Was it just your mistake, or did you want some unobvious way of character matching that would produce that kind of result?

Comment: Thanks mate i did make a mistate in my result sum :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
Details %>% separate(FirstName, c("Person", "last"), " ") %>%
            group_by(Person) %>%
            summarise(Appearances = n(), 
                      "Total Points" = sum(Points)) %>%
            left_join(Results, .)
```